# Area of paraboloid on top of a triangle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the area of a paraboloid $z=y^2$ that lies on top of the triangle whose tips are located at the origin and $(0,1)$ & $(1,1)$.

The situation looks as follows:

[image]

However, I'm not entirely sure how I can integrate this to find the area of the "patch" that the $xy$-triangle bounds. Should I define equations for the different lines that the points on the triangle defines or what? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y)=y^2$

$$S=\iint_T\sqrt{f'_x{^2}+f'_y{^2}+1}\,dA$$
where $f'_x$ and $f'_y$ are the partial derivatives
$$\int _0^1\int _x^1\sqrt{(2 y)^2+0^2+1}\,dydx=\frac{1}{12} \left(5 \sqrt{5}-1\right)$$

---

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on where is the integrand coming from?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it helps. @DanielLi

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate the area as follows
\begin{align}
Area&= \int_S \sqrt{1+(z_x’)^2 +(z_y’)^2}\>dxdy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \sqrt{1+4y^2}\>dxdy\\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+4y^2}y\>dy\\
 &=\frac14  \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+t^2}t\>dt\>\>\>\>\>\>(t=2y)\\
&=\frac1{12}(5\sqrt5-1)
\end{align}

Comment: What are $z'_{x}$ and $z'_{y}$ representing?